# Is there any way to do JIRA-Dashboard style project management/overview with Bugzilla?

Tags: dashboard, bugzilla

I need roadmap view, overall bug graphs, multiple pieces of information on one screen - can this work with Bugzilla? Eclipse-based plugins etc are usable... but solutions like yoxel that need access to the Bugzilla SQL DB itself are probably not workable.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That may be a little off-course, but have you looked at Deskzilla? You can build project breakdown or roadmap using nested queries and tabular distribution. It doesn't have graphs though.

Igor

*Disclaimer: I work for ALM Works, the company behind Deskzilla.*

Comment: I tried Deskzilla, it is an excellent product. I used to think that I absolutely needed Bugzilla charts to understand what was going on, now I realize that the tabular info also carries a lot of value in itself, esp when mined along the correct dimensions. Kudos if you're working for this company.

Comment: Thanks :) Feel free to throw in feature requests on our forum.